# How do I make IDEA/PyCharm treat @tf_export correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, intellij-idea, pycharm, tf.keras

How do I make IDEA/PyCharm treat `@tf_export` annotation correctly ?

I switched to TF 1.12 and for following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
```

I see IDEA highlighting import of `layers`.

[image]

I cannot navigate to declaration of `Dense` by right-clicking on it.

Code correctly executes.

Is there way to fix this ?

Comment: Known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34174

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```py
import tensorflow.python.keras
from keras import Sequential, layers
```